# Why do backbone has sync method in models as well as collections?

Tags: backbone.js, synchronization

Anyways using sync method only in collection or only in model can suffice, then why do they have to sync at both the places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both `sync()` methods are just proxies to a common `Backbone.sync()` method:

- [Model.sync()](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L231-234)
- [Collection.sync()](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L584-587)
- [Backbone.sync()](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1311)

Collection always delegate in the `Model.sync()` for individual operations over its individual models like: `create`, `remove` and so on. But Collection uses its own `sync()` in the `fetch()` operation due it is very different to `fetch` a Model or a Collection, for example: the URL follows another patter and the backend layer should respond different.

In the other hand I see the `Backbone.sync()` as a private method and I try to not use it directly, if I'm doing this I don't feel well. I think the `sync()` method is a handler point to allow you to overwrite completely the *backend synchronization* a method that you can overwrite to implement different *persistance layers* as for example using *LocalStorage*. But not for be called directly.

As @JMM has said in the comments, the `Model.sync()` and `Collection.sync()` is also a good point to be overwrote to make it *"does something custom and then calls `Backbone.sync()` to carry on as usual"*.

Comment: You can implement a `sync()` method that does something custom and then calls `Backbone.sync()` to carry on as usual. You don't have to completely replace the built-in implementation, or only define a `sync()` method to change the persistence strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone doesn't have a `sync` -method in models and collections by default, but both models and the collections have methods (`fetch` for both models and collections and `save`, `destroy` for models) that use the `Backbone.sync` -method to make ajax-calls. [Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync), [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-162)

The methods that use `Backbone.sync` check for the existence of a `sync` method for the individual collection or model, so the default functionality of sync can be overwritten for everything by overwriting the `Backbone.sync` or for specific parts by extending a model or collection that needs custom sync with a `sync` -function.

As to why both models and collections have the capability to synchronize with the server: ***flexibility***. If only collections would have the syncing capability, then you couldn't have individual models, and if only models would have syncing capability, how would you fetch large batches of models initially from the server. There is no downside in having syncing capabilities for models and collections, so **why not?**

My counter-question for you: How would having sync on only the other suffice?

Comment: You are right. Backbone has sync method not the models and collections. Twas my actual question but couldn't ask it properly. Pardon me. And no answer for your counter question as now i have realized why we need sync on the both the sides. I thought can't we just sync collection every time the model changes, but that is not good.